# Correct way of handling errors with Spring WebClient (Reactor HTTPClient)

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor-netty

I have a basic application that downloads data from a website, but the request often returns 404 not found errors or a `PrematureCloseException`. My question is how can I implement my client in a way that it automatically retries if it encounters a `PrematureCloseException`, but allows to handle 404 later in the stream while also setting a cache when the request is successful.

Current code:

```java
 httpClient.get()
            .uri(URL)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(ByteArrayResource.class)
//Retry until the server responds "correctly"
            .retryWhen(Retry.indefinitely().filter(t -> t instanceof PrematureCloseException))
            .map(ByteArrayResource::getByteArray)
            .doOnNext(next -> cache.set(next)) //Set the cache only if the request is successful

//Passed to another method
            .ifError(error -> logger.error("Error encountered {}", error)) //Somehow handle all exceptions (not the PrematureCloseExceptions)
            .subscribe(data -> {
               //Successful request
            })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Your `retryWhen` is configured correctly, and your `doOnNext` handles the cache correctly.

To handle errors, you can use [`Flux.doOnError`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#doOnError-java.util.function.Consumer-), which works similar as `doOnNext`.